# How to sort config labels in natTable as well? (Is there a simple way to get relative coordinates from a nattable?)

Tags: java, sorting, nattable, nebula

I'm using the natTable's config label as an identifier to color each cell in the table.

config Labels are assigned to the table in absolute coordinates.

However, when sorting, the corresponding label is in absolute coordinates, so when the values ​​are sorted, I want the labels to be sorted as well. What should I do in this case?

Can I change the config label to relative coordinates?

If possible, I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on column and row numbers but on some real information. The feature you are talking about is named "conditional styling" and the cell coordinates are not a very good condition. Especially because of the behavior you describe.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_labels

You could add the label accumulator on the `DataLayer`, which is mostly the only layer where index == position. You could also implement a index-position-transformation in you accumulator. But dependent on the way you implemented sorting, the underlying list structure might change, e.g. when using the GlazedLists SortedList. In that way there is no way to identify the cell coordinate reliably.

Comment: thanks for answering

So, is there any other way to repeat the process of deleting the old label accumulator and registering a new label accumulator every time it is sorted?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Therefore no. You need to find a way to add the labels by a condition that is not based on cell coordinates. If you focus on cell content instead of cell position it works with any transformation.

Comment: thanks for answering!!I found a way!

Let each cell in natTable have an object,
I added a config label by checking the value of the object.

When I do this, there is no problem with sorting.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried to explain! BTW, every cell should have an object, or what are you trying to show in a cell?

Comment: yes! 
If the data value in the cell is not valid, I tried to display the background section and font color in red. Now it will be fine automatically thanks!